# No response on stdout

Tags: python

I'm doing a coding challenge and every time I submit I get a the wrong answer with a "No response on stdout" Do you know what I can do? Here is the link to the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup

```
def countingValleys(n, s):

    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input())

    s = input()

    result = countingValleys(n, s)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()

    N=int(input())
    S = input()
    L = 0
    V = 0
    for el in S:
        if s == 'U':
            L+= 1
            if L == 0:
                V += 1
        else:
            L -= 1
    print(V)
```

Comment: And what can we do without code?

Comment: I just posted it

Answer (score 0):

You are probably returning the value instead of using the `print()` function. The problem specification says that you have to print it.

Comment: I have used the print function. You can check my code above